# Typescript catch variable renamed when compiled trough ts2gas using google clasp

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script

I'm working on local typescript code which I compile to google app script using google clasp. Once this is compiled and I look at the generated .gs code I see the try catch is transformed into a switch case, and the error variable from the catch block in case 3 is assigned with a unique name while the usage of this variable isn't renamed.

Typescript code before compiling:

```
const getData = async (request: GetDataRequest): Promise<GetDataResponse> => {
  if (!request) { return; }

  try {
    const requestedFields: Fields = getFields().forIds(
      request.fields.map( ({name}) => name)
    );

    const response: CampaignData[]      = await fetchMailChimpData();
    const data:     GetDataRows         = parseResponseToDataRows(response, requestedFields);

    return {
      schema: requestedFields.build(),
      rows:   data
    };
  }
  catch (error) {
    connector
      .newUserError()
      .setDebugText('Error fetching data from MailChimp API. Exception details: ' + error)
      .setText(error)
      .throwException();
  }
}
```

Google script code after compiling:

```
var getData = function (request) { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, Promise, function () {
  var requestedFields, response, data, error_1;
  return __generator(this, function (_a) {
    switch (_a.label) {
      case 0:
        if (!request) {
          return [2 /*return*/];
        }
        _a.label = 1;
      case 1:
        _a.trys.push([1, 3, , 4]);
        requestedFields = getFields().forIds(request.fields.map(function (_a) {
          var name = _a.name;
          return name;
        }));
        return [4 /*yield*/, fetchMailChimpData()];
      case 2:
        response = _a.sent();
        data = parseResponseToDataRows(response, requestedFields);
        return [2 /*return*/, {
          schema: requestedFields.build(),
          rows: data
        }];
      case 3:
        error_1 = _a.sent();
        connector
          .newUserError()
          .setDebugText('Error fetching data from MailChimp API. Exception details: ' + error)
          .setText(error)
          .throwException();
        return [3 /*break*/, 4];
      case 4: return [2 /*return*/];
    }
  });
}); };
```

In the typescript code the error gets defined in the catch statement, but in case 3 the error gets defined as error_1. While the other usages are not renamed to error_1. Does someone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a basic `try...catch` sample. After compiling it, it is not getting replaced by a switch case, but kept as it is. Can you provide a full code sample that can be used to reproduce this?

Comment: Hey tanks for the response. Sorry for the late reply but I updated the code in the question to include the full getter. I think try catch blocks only get transformed in an async function like this. But I still don't know why the variable would change like this, while the usage isn't changed.

Comment: Weird! Have you been able to come up with a simplified code that can be used to reproduce this, so that what's going on when compiling gets a bit clearer?

Comment: I found the problem and just answered my own question. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution for this issue. We have multiple scripts in a project, each in their own folder. When compiling the typescript files will look for a tsconfig file. But because the ts config file wasn't in the script folder but rather in the project folder it didn't find a tsconfig file, and thus using the wrong compiler settings.

The solution we applied was making symlinks to the projects tsconfig file in each script folder.